onSelect not working on commandInput of shadcn
I am using shadcn for a React.js project of my own. I am trying to create a component with Popover and Command, Command items components from shadcn. However the onSelect inside the CommandItem are not working. The items are grayed out and I can select them. The last CommandItem (Create Store) is selected by default and if I click enter the modal do open but I can get it to work when clicking and I can't change options.

Here is the code:
"use client"

import { Store } from "@prisma/client";
import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Check, ChevronsUpDown, PlusCircle, Store as StoreIcon } from "lucide-react";
import { useState } from "react";

import { Popover, PopoverContent, PopoverTrigger } from "@/components/ui/popover"
import { useStoreModal } from "@/hooks/use-store-modal";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import {
    Command, 
    CommandEmpty, 
    CommandGroup, 
    CommandInput, 
    CommandItem, 
    CommandList, 
    CommandSeparator 
} from "@/components/ui/command";
import { Input } from "./ui/input";


type PopoverTriggerProps = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof PopoverTrigger>

interface StoreSwitcherProps extends PopoverTriggerProps {
    items: Store[];
}

export default function StoreSwitcher({
    className,
    items = []
}: StoreSwitcherProps) {
    const storeModal = useStoreModal();
    const params = useParams();
    const router = useRouter();

    const formattedItems = items.map((item) => ({
        value: item.id,
        label: item.name,
    }));

    const currentStore = formattedItems.find((item) => item.value === params.storeId)

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    
    const onStoreSelect = (store: {value: String, label: string}) => {
        setOpen(false);
        router.push(`/${store.value}`);
    };

    const handleSelect = () => {
        console.log("Selected:");
    };

    return (
        <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
            <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                <Button
                    variant="outline"
                    size="sm"
                    role="combobox"
                    aria-expanded={open}
                    aria-label="Select a store"
                    className={cn("w-[200px] justify-between", className)}
                >
                    <StoreIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4"/>
                    {currentStore?.label}
                    <ChevronsUpDown className="ml-auto h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50"/>
                </Button>
            </PopoverTrigger>
            <PopoverContent className="2-[200px] p-0">
                <Command>
                    <CommandList>
                        <CommandInput placeholder="Search store..."/>
                        <CommandEmpty>No store found.</CommandEmpty>
                        <CommandGroup heading="Stores">
                            {formattedItems.map((store) => (
                                <CommandItem
                                    key={store.value}
                                    onSelect={() => onStoreSelect(store)}
                                    className="text-sm"
                                >
                                    <StoreIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4"/>
                                    {store.label}
                                    <Check 
                                        className={cn(
                                            "ml-auto h-4 w-4",
                                            currentStore?.value === store.value
                                                ? "opacity-100"
                                                : "opacity-0"
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </CommandItem>
                            ))}
                        </CommandGroup>
                    </CommandList>
                    <CommandSeparator />
                    <CommandList>
                        <CommandGroup>
                            <CommandItem
                                onSelect={() =>  {
                                    setOpen(false);
                                    storeModal.onOpen();
                                }}
                            >
                                <PlusCircle className="mr-2 h-5    w-5"/>
                                Create Store
                            </CommandItem>
                        </CommandGroup>
                    </CommandList>
                </Command>
            </PopoverContent>
        </Popover>
    );
}


Detailed answers is given in the link:
https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/2944#issuecomment-1985153126
From your @/components/ui/command file check for CommandItem component and update data-[disabled] class to data-[disabled='true']

From your @/components/ui/command file check for CommandItem component and update data-[disabled] class to data-[disabled='true']
this worked for me.
following the same guy on youtube 
